# concatenation $scope.something with string in angluarjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In special situation I want to modify $scope.newItem to concatnate with dynamic value. eg. `$scope.newItem1, $scope.newItem2, $scope.newItem3` and so on where the 1,2,3 is dynamic variable.

my problem 
I tried "$scope.newItem"+id but it turned into a string.

Comment: Not clear, can you detail the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after $scope['newItem'+id]?

Comment: after? what do u mean by are you after?

Comment: I just meant is that what you are searchig for -- as you have accepted it, I assume.. yes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new properties to `$scope`, or any javascript object for that matter, you can use the indexer notation:

```
var obj = {},
    i = 3;

obj["myProp" + i] = "Bob";

console.log(obj.myProp3); // Bob
```

But I'm unclear as to whether this is what you are looking for or not.